# TCPDF execution timedout for larger table of SQL records

Tags: php, sql, tcpdf

I am a beginner to php,I am using `tcpdf` class for generating `PDF docs` (contains html tables) for the `SQL data`.It converts the data as pdf for limited rows(200 rows but it takes 120sec ),but it can not able to do that for above 200 rows(shows maximum execution timed out).

I am using `writehtml()` function for writing html tables.

Is there any way to process larger records?

```
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
$pdf = new TCPDF('P', PDF_UNIT,'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false); 
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(false);

$pdf->SetHeaderData('logo.jpg',40,'companyhead',"addressline1,asdasd,\nxxxfgh-1234");
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, 30, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

//selecting from the database and fetching each records
$query = "SELECT * FROM test3 WHERE month='$month[0]' AND year='$year[0]'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{ 

//here goes some calculations with retrieved records    

//add a page
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Times', 'B', 15);
$pdf->Write(0,'Pay slip for'.$month.','.$year.'', '', 0, 'C', true, 0, false, false, 0);

$pdf->Ln(); 
$pdf->SetFont('Times', '', 10);

//html table with the processed records goes here
$table ='<table width="555" style="border:1px solid black;" align="center">
//table contents
</table>';


$pdf->writeHTML($table, true, false, false, false, '');
$pdf->Ln(); 
$pdf->Ln(); 

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//html table 
$table ='<table width="540" align="center" style="border:1px solid black;">
//table contents 
</table>';

$pdf->writeHTML($table, true, false, false, false, '');
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$pdf->Ln(); 
$pdf->Ln(); 
//adding some text content to the pdf
$pdf->Write(0, 'Note:The information provided to you is confidential do not share it with others', '', 0, 'L', true, 0, false, false, 0);
$pdf->lastPage();

}

$pdf->Output('unnamed.pdf', 'I');
```

Comment: Is the generating task ongoing or once off?

Comment: It is not generating, the execution gets timed out for larger records.I tried changing the execution limit too.It doesn't work that much.

Comment: That is not what I meant. Is this php script going to be used regularly or is it only used to generate the pdf files once? My answer depends on how often you are doing this db to pdf conversion.

Comment: It is only used to generate pdf files once by fetching the data from SQL dB.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to process only some row at time and then force output with ob_flush function (https://www.php.net/ob_flush)

eg:

```
$chunk =0 ;
for($rows as $k => $v) {
    $data_to_write = process_elem($k,$v);
    write_to_pdf($data_to_write);
    if($chunk++ == 50) {
       ob_flush;
       $chunk=0;
    }
}
```

If you post your code I can help you in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Use a work queue such as Beanstalk. Instead of trying to work through all of the records at once, get the basic record id's from the main page. In the worker process, which will process one record at a time in in the background to actually assemble the PDF. Your initial script finishes quicker and you can monitor the queue in realtime. Your system will get through the records no matter how many you throw at it.

Beanstalk: http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/
You will need the PHP library to use it: https://github.com/pda/pheanstalk

Once you get it, you can offload many background tasks with it such as logging, sending messages or image resize tasks to name a few of the workers I have setup.

Good Luck!

Comment: I solved the problem by installing XCACHE, It really speeds up the operation.Thank you for your information I will use your technique for sending emails and image re sizing.

Comment: Thats great, no problem at all.